# File open error - operation not permitted , getting this error on macos when trying to run an application server

Tags: marklogic

I have created a marklogic application server which hosts a top-songs application configured on port 8040, root directory is the path to the application folder.

I have tried giving read & write access to every folder and file but wasn't able to resolve the issue.

A similar error occurred when I tried inserting documents through query console using xquery/javascript. permission denied.

> 500 Internal Server Error
> SVC-FILOPN: File open error: open '/Users/rishabh/Downloads/mls-semantics/projects/top-songs/index.xqy': Operation not permitted
> in / [1.0-ml]

Comment: Verify the permissions and ownership of the files. Also, the Downloads directory. The MarkLogic process needs to be able to see and read/write. Maybe try running outside of the downloads dir and put into a specific directory. You might also consider using a Modules database instead of the filesystem.

Comment: moving the application folder out of the Downloads folder worked, thanks a lot @MadsHansen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the permissions and ownership of the files. Also, the Downloads directory.

The MarkLogic process needs to be able to see and read/write. Maybe try running outside of the downloads dir and put into a specific directory.

You might also consider using a Modules database instead of the filesystem.